# Are http headers shared across browser tabs?

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers, httpcookie

I am aware that cookies are send from client(web browser) to server([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) for requests made across tabs or windows of same browsers. So http cookies are same across different browsers tabs for a given domain.

But from my experience, the same is not true for http headers. If a browser tab accesses server ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) and the server sends an header - `"mycustomeheader: "i am example.com"`, then this header will not be available to other tabs with in the same browser window or other windows of same browser.

Is the above understanding correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because HTTP headers are per request, because you send or expect JSON/XML/HTML per request, for example Content length header value usually will be different depends on request body

But cookies are [per domain](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/161111/why-dont-browsers-restrict-cookies-per-tab-to-combat-csrf-attacks/161114#161114)

> Every time your browser makes an http request, it checks the (local) cookie database for any cookies that have a domain matching that of the request; if it finds any, it sends them along to the server

Comment: its good to see some confirmation. ++1;